# Checking if user authored an entry in another channel while in loop, N+1 problem

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, elementquery

I have 2 channels set up: **Channel A** and **Channel B**.  I also have public registration so users can log in and fill out two forms (**Form A** and **Form B**), each form creating an entry in their respective channel with the user as the author.  The user can only create an entry in Channel B if they already have an entry in Channel A.

To get all the users who have an entry in Channel A but not in Channel B, I tried writing something like this in my class:

```
public function getUsersWithoutChannelBEntry()
{
    $channel_A_entries = Entry::find()
        ->sectionId(1)
        ->all();

    $userIds = [];
    foreach ($channel_A_entries as $entry) {

        $channel_B_entry_exists = Entry::find()
            ->sectionId(2)
            ->authorId($entry->authorId)
            ->exists();

        if (! $channel_B_entry_exists) {
            $userIds[] = $entry->authorId;
        }

    }

    return User::find()
        ->id($userIds)
        ->all();
}
```

However, this creates an N+1 problem. I have roughly 200 users, so potentially 200 entries in either channel, and thus a lot of db queries and a substantially larger load time.

As an alternative approach, I've also tried looping through Channel A, adding each author ID into an array (Array A), then doing the same with Channel B making Array B.  Then I use `array_diff()` to extract the author IDs that are in Array A but not in Array B.  However, this still causes a bit of long load time.

I've looked into eager loading, but that seems to only apply to related fields.

Is there a more efficient way to get all users who authored a Channel A entry but not Channel B entry?

Answer (score 1):

There's one bit missing in the constrains you explain above, do users end up with 1 entry **only** per channel so a total of 2 posts max?

If so, we know that:

- each users can have a max of 2 posts
- a user cannot post in B is they haven't completed their post in A

So assuming this first condition is also true (2 entries/user) you could just loop through users post count looking for those with less than 2 posts and they would automatically be the users who haven't posted in B..? Just a shot in the dark :)